# SSMS query editing: possible to remove a field and have the matching value removed?

Tags: sql, ssms

I work with large queries in SSMS.  It would be fantastic if I could easily match up the comma-separated values with the comma-separated field names.  I often delete a field, and then have to hunt for the matching value before the query is valid again.

Surely there is a way to find the matching value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName
WHERE ','+ColumnName+',' LIKE '%,searchword,%'
```

Or:

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName
WHERE
ColumnName LIKE '%,' + @searchword + ',%' 
OR ColumnName LIKE @searchword + ',%' 
OR ColumnName LIKE '%,' + @searchword 
OR ColumnName =  @searchword
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, manually reformatting the query to help make it easier to spot the field I want to remove, isn't feasible since I have to do this with hundreds of queries.